# Changing the bounds of a drawn rectangle in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am developing an application using Google Maps Javascript where the user can draw a rectangle on a map so that the bounds of the area can be used to query a database for data within the area they have selected. I would also like to have HTML input boxes so that they can edit the bounds by typing in the latitude and longitude if they need to. I can do this, but when they change the value, I would like the map to update.

I understand that the HTML `<input>` tag will need an `onchange` attribute, whose value is a call to a function that will update the map. However, I am unsure of what to put in the function to make the rectangle bounds update.

This is the Javascript code I am using to create the map the user uses to make their selection:

```
function initialize() {
        //some code omitted here
        var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
           drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
           drawingControl: true,
           drawingControlOptions: {
              drawingModes: [
                 google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
              ]
           },
           rectangleOptions: {
              // some code omitted here
           }
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event){
           // when the overlay is complete, update the html form fields
           update_bounds_fields(event);

           // don't allow the user to draw more than 1 rectangle
           // (disable drawing controls after the first one has been drawn)
           drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
           drawingManager.setOptions({
              drawingControl: false
           });

           // The drawn area is editable with mouse so also want to
           // update the html form when the area is edited
           google.maps.event.addListener(event.overlay, 'bounds_changed', function() {
              update_bounds_fields(event);
           });
        });

        drawingManager.setMap(map);
     }
```

The HTML code for the form is as follows:

```
<form name="bounds_form" action="index.php" method="get">
     <input type="text" id="northwest-latitude" name="nw-lat" onchange="update_map_bounds();"></input></br>
     <input type="text" id="northwest-longitude" name="nw-lng" onchange="update_map_bounds();"</input></br>
     <input type="text" id="southeast-latitude" name="se-lat" onchange="update_map_bounds();"></input></br>
     <input type="text" id="southeast-longitude" name="se-lng" onchange="update_map_bounds();"></input></br>
     <center><input type="submit" id="submit-button" onclick="validate_bounds(bounds_form)"></center>
  </form>
```

So, whenever the value of one of the form fields is changed, I would like to update the rectangle shown on the map accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. make the rectangle accessible in the global scope:

```
var rectangle;  // needs to be in the global scope, outside of an function

google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (event) {
    // when the overlay is complete, update the html form fields
    update_bounds_fields(event);
    rectangle = event.overlay;
```

2. change the bounds of the rectangle in the onchange function

```
function update_map_bounds() {
    var north = parseFloat(document.getElementById('northwest-latitude').value);
    var south = parseFloat(document.getElementById('southeast-latitude').value);
    var east = parseFloat(document.getElementById('southeast-longitude').value);
    var west = parseFloat(document.getElementById('northwest-longitude').value);
    if (!isNaN(north) && !isNaN(south) && !isNaN(west) && !isNaN(east)) {
        var NE = new google.maps.LatLng(north, east);
        var SW = new google.maps.LatLng(south, west);
        var newRect = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(SW,NE);
        rectangle.setBounds(newRect);
        map.fitBounds(newRect);
    }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/L3dma4x1/2/)

code snippet:

```js
var map;
var rectangle;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }); //some code omitted here
  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
      ]
    },
    rectangleOptions: {
      editable: true
        // some code omitted here
    }
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
    // when the overlay is complete, update the html form fields
    update_bounds_fields(event);
    rectangle = event.overlay;

    // don't allow the user to draw more than 1 rectangle
    // (disable drawing controls after the first one has been drawn)
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
    drawingManager.setOptions({
      drawingControl: false
    });

    // The drawn area is editable with mouse so also want to
    // update the html form when the area is edited
    google.maps.event.addListener(event.overlay, 'bounds_changed', function() {
      update_bounds_fields(event);
    });
  });

  drawingManager.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function update_bounds_fields(event) {
  document.getElementById('northwest-latitude').value = event.overlay.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
  document.getElementById('northwest-longitude').value = event.overlay.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
  document.getElementById('southeast-latitude').value = event.overlay.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
  document.getElementById('southeast-longitude').value = event.overlay.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
}

function update_map_bounds() {
  var north = parseFloat(document.getElementById('northwest-latitude').value);
  var south = parseFloat(document.getElementById('southeast-latitude').value);
  var east = parseFloat(document.getElementById('southeast-longitude').value);
  var west = parseFloat(document.getElementById('northwest-longitude').value);
  if (!isNaN(north) && !isNaN(south) && !isNaN(west) && !isNaN(east)) {
    var NE = new google.maps.LatLng(north, east);
    var SW = new google.maps.LatLng(south, west);
    var newRect = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(SW, NE);
    rectangle.setBounds(newRect);
    map.fitBounds(newRect);
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=drawing"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<form name="bounds_form" action="index.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" id="northwest-latitude" name="nw-lat" onchange="update_map_bounds();" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="northwest-longitude" name="nw-lng" onchange="update_map_bounds();" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="southeast-latitude" name="se-lat" onchange="update_map_bounds();" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="southeast-longitude" name="se-lng" onchange="update_map_bounds();" />
  <br/>
  <center>
    <input type="submit" id="submit-button" onclick="validate_bounds(bounds_form)" />
  </center>
</form>
```